# Asymptotics for the tail of $L_p$ norms

Tags: real-analysis

Let $1<p<\infty$ be fixed and $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$. I would like to obtain some asymptotic estimate for the function 
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
F(R)=\lVert f\chi_{\{\lvert x \rvert >R\}}\rVert_{L^p}=\left(\int_{\lvert x\rvert>R}\lvert f(x)\rvert^p\, dx\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}\qquad \text{ as }R\to +\infty,
\end{equation}
under suitable further assumptions on $f$. Here's a conjecture based on the heuristic that a *lower* summability index corresponds to a *faster* decay at infinity:

> **Question**. Assume that $f\in L^p\cap L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$. Is it true that 
>   $$\tag{2}F(R)\le C_f \cdot R^{-\frac{1}{p'}}?$$
>   If (2) does not hold, can we give some other bound on $F$?

Here $C_f>0$ is a constant that depends on $f$ (probably through one or more of its norms).

Comment: Have you played around with Holder's inequality? That'd be my first consideration.

Comment: @nayrb: Of course. The problem is that the obvious approach of writing $$f^p=f^{p-\alpha}f^\alpha$$ does not lead to useful conclusions as Holder's inequality trivializes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can get $C_f$ to depend only on the norm of $f$, because $f(\cdot - y)$ has the same $L^1$ and $L^p$ as $f$.

I think you can use this idea to find a counterexample to your conjecture: let $g$ be a function whose support is in the unit ball, and whose $L^1$ and $L^p$ norms are non-zero.  Let $a_n > 0$ be a summable sequence.  Pick $y_n \in \mathbb R^d$ to be a sequence with $|y_n - y_m| > 2$.  Then by adjusting $a_n$ and $y_n$, you should be able to find an $f(x) = \sum_n a_n g(x - y_n)$ such that
$$ \sup_{R>0} {\|f \chi_{|x|>R}\|}_p R^{1/p'} = \infty .$$

Comment: This method reduces the problem to the existence of a sequence $a_n>0$ such that $$\sum_n a_n<\infty$$ and the tail $$\sum_{n=N}^\infty a_n^p$$ has a decay slower than $$N^{-\frac{p}{p'}}=N^{-(p-1)}.$$ I guess that the old example of the harmonic series with iterated logarithms $$\sum a_n\quad \text{with}\quad a_n=\frac{1}{n\log(n)\log(\log(n))\ldots \log^{\circ k}(n)} $$might came in handy here. I'm doing some computations now.

Comment: Actually, I think you can use any old summable sequence, e.g. $a_n = 2^{-n}$.  It is the choice of $y_n$ that makes it converge as slowly as you like.

Comment: Yes, yes I think that I am just implementing your idea in a different way. See my answer below. Instead of choosing judiciously the spacing in $y_n$, I took a sequence $a_n$ which is sparse, that is, has a lot of zeroes. This is essentially the same I guess.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I agree, and you are correct.  You implemented the idea in a different way.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I believe that I learned something from this discussion.

Answer (score 2):

**Claim**. The conjecture is false. Indeed, proceeding as in Stephen Montgomery-Smith's answer, one may see that the problem is reduced to the asymptotic estimate of the tails 
$$S_N^{(p)}=\sum_{n=N}^\infty a_n^p, $$
where $a_n\ge 0$ is a summable sequence (i.e. $\sum_n a_n < \infty$). If the conjecture were true, then $S^{(p)}_N$ should decay as $N^{1-p}$ (or faster). However, we can find examples of sequences $a_n$ such that $S_N^{(p)}$ converges only logarithmically.

Namely, if we take a $\alpha>1$ and we take
$$
a_n=\begin{cases} k^{-\alpha}, & n=2^k \\ 0, & \mathrm{otherwise}\end{cases}, $$
we obtain
$$
S_N^{(p)}=\sum_{k\ge \left\lfloor \frac{\log N}{\log 2}\right\rfloor}k^{-\alpha p} \ge c \left(\left\lfloor \frac{\log N}{\log 2}\right\rfloor\right)^{1-\alpha p},
$$ 
for some constant $c>0$. This is enough to disprove the conjecture. $\square$

---

**EDIT** (*in response to Stephen Montgomery-Smith's comment below*). Here's a more general construction, proving that no asymptotic estimate for $F(R)$ can exist.

Let $\phi\colon (0, \infty)\to (0, \infty)$ be a monotonically increasing function such that $\phi(R)\to \infty$ as $R\to \infty$. We claim that a function $f\in L^1\cap L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$ exists such that 
$$\sup_{R>0} \lVert f\chi_{\{\lvert x \rvert > R\}}\rVert_{L^p}\phi(R)=\infty.$$
To build $f$ we first take a nonvanishing bump function $g\ge 0$ supported in the unit ball. Then we set 
$$
\tilde{\phi}(R)=\phi(R)^{\frac{p}{2}\frac{1}{2p-1}},$$
observing that $\tilde{\phi}(R)$ increases monotonically towards $\infty$, and we set 
\begin{equation}
y_n=[\tilde{\phi}]^{-1}(n) \mathbf{e}_1.
\end{equation}
Here $\cdot^{-1}$ refers to functional inversion and $\mathbf{e}_1=(1, 0,\ldots, 0)\in \mathbb{R}^d$. Then we set $a_n=n^{-2}$ and we define $f$ to be 
\begin{equation}
f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n g(x-y_n).
\end{equation}
Since $\lVert f\rVert_{L^1} = C_1\sum_{n} a_n$ and $\lVert f\rVert_{L^p}^p=C_p \sum_n a_n^p$, the function $f$ is in $L^1\cap L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$. We have
$$
\begin{split}
\lVert f\chi_{\{\lvert x \rvert > R\}}\rVert_{L^p}^p &\ge C \sum_{n> \tilde{\phi}(R)} n^{-2p} \\
&\ge C \tilde{\phi}(R)^{1-2p}= C\phi(R)^{-\frac{p}{2}}.
\end{split}$$
Therefore 
$$\sup_{R>0} \lVert f\chi_{\{\lvert x \rvert > R\}}\rVert_{L^p}^p\phi(R)^p=\sup_{R>0}\phi^{\frac{p}{2}}(R)=\infty.$$

Comment: I took the idea for the sequence $a_n$ from [this old answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/57047/8157) by Did.

Comment: I think that what you really want to show is that there doesn't exist any function $\phi:(0,\infty)\to(0,\infty)$ with $\limsup_{R\to\infty} \phi(R) = \infty$ such that there doesn't exist a function $f \in L^1 \cap L^p$ with $\sup_{R>0} \phi(R) {\|f\chi_{|x|>R}\|}_p = \infty$.  The idea is something like $y_n = n \phi^{-1}(2^n)$, or something similar if $\phi$ is not invertible.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith: I followed your suggestion and added an edit to my answer. I think that the question is completely settled now.